# XSLT 2.0: Transform simple date into reversed date format

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I can't seem to find a solution for my XSLT 2.0 transformation related problem.
This is the source XML:

```
<reportInterval>
    <startDate>01.07.2016</startDate>
</reportInterval>
```

This is the part of XSLT transformation sheet:

```
<xsl:attribute name="per_start">
     <xsl:value-of select="format-date(reportInterval/startDate, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

The error is the following:

```
Error at char 25 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 17 column 116 of Transactions.xsl:
  FORG0001: Invalid date "01.07.2016" (When year exceeds 4 digits, leading zeroes are not allowed)
  in built-in template rule
```

I think this is related to the fact, that XSL doesn't understand the date `String` provided. Is there any other way to do the required conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Construct an `xs:date` from your original input format by reordering the components into the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Is that date supposed to be 1st July or 7th January?

Comment: @MichaelKay that's 1st of July.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you view this as purely string manipulation you could just do something like this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="replace(reportInterval/startDate, '(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})', '$3-$2-$1')"/>
```

This would return "2017-07-01".

If you wanted to cast this as a date, and output other formats, then consider this XSLT...

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <date>
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="replace(reportInterval/startDate, '(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})', '$3-$2-$1')"/> 
        <xsl:attribute name="per_start">
             <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($date), '[MN] [D01], [Y0001]')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </date>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Great solution!

Comment: This solution seems to be assuming the input is dd.mm.yyyy. If it's mm.dd.yyyy then the code needs amending accordingly.

Comment: @Tim C can you please advise, if possible, which of the above variants is faster? Inline string manipulation or date conversion? I think string manipulation.. but would like to hear your input :)

Comment: Well, with the data conversion it is still doing the string manipulation first, so doing just string manipulation would be faster in this case.